# Can't find a mistake - no paragraphs found when text is added to a data file

Tags: c

I wrote a program to count the paragraphs in the text. When the data file is empty, it shows that there are 0 paragraphs, but when I add text, it shows nothing. Please help me with this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(void)
{
    int p = 0; //---Paragraphs
    char ch;
    FILE *failas;
    failas = fopen("nuskaitymas.txt" , "r");

    while (ch = fgetc(failas) != EOF)
    {
        while (ch != '\n')
        {
            p++;
        }
    }

    printf("number of paragraphs %d", p);
}
```

Comment: `ch = fgetc(failas) != EOF` is not the same as `(ch = fgetc(failas)) != EOF`, which is probably what you meant.

Comment: Instead of the inner `while()` loop, try `if (ch == '\n') p++;`

Comment: "The C Programming Language" <-- read it and understand operator precedence.

Comment: Note: use `int ch` rather than `char ch`.  `fgets()` returns 257 different values (EOF and 0 - 255).

Comment: @AudriusŠimoliūnas Did yo solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to check that `fopen` succeeded

```
failas = fopen("nuskaitymas.txt", "r");
if (failas == NULL)
    return -1;
```

then

```
while (ch != '\n')
```

will never end replace it with

```
if (ch == '\n')
    p++;
```

also, this is not right

```
while (ch = fgetc(failas) != EOF)
```

it's because `!=` operator has higher precedence than `=` operator, so it will be evaluated first and then the result will be assigned to `ch`.

do it this way

```
while ((ch = fgetc(failas)) != EOF)
```

And last but not least declare `ch` as `int` since `fgetc` returns `int`.

Comment: @iharob that is NOT the reason

Comment: @WeatherVane So then what is the reason?, I am sorry wasn't sure about it.

Comment: The reason is because `!=` has greater precedence than `=`

Comment: Thank you again @WeatherVane [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) link shows that assignment operators have almost the lowest precedence. I got it, now I'm not going to forget it.

Comment: three small suggestions: 1.) use `EOF != (ch = ..)` instead of `(ch = ...) != EOF` because it will produce a compiler error if the parentheses are forgot. 2.) `fclose` the opened file before returning from `main`. 3.) (very minor) I would suggest terminating the `prinf`'d string with a newline, to avoid a messed up commandline.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to close your file, so put the line

```
fclose(failas);
```

at the end of your code.  Your next problem is how you are incrementing `p`.  Each time you go through the loop and `ch` is not `\n`, p gets increased.  if you have a large enough file, p will have problems because you will exceed the size of the integer.  change the inner loop to an `if` statement, like this:

```
if(ch == '\n'){
  p++;
}
```

that should clear up all of your problems.

Comment: I don't like this answer, it does not address the ciritical logic problem. maybe it should be a comment to @iharob's answer, to point out the missing fclose instead?